# My osmdroid and mobile atlas creator only show empty tiles

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

Hello I'm doing an offline map.
I can't see the map tiles that I created from Mobile Atlas Creator. I'm using MapQuest and Tiel Format PNG, and it doesn't show any kind of problems and generates correctly the .APK
I tried all

- I put my .zip file in /sdcard/osmdroid/
- i changed my first folder inside of my .zip MapQuest by MapquestOSM
- I reviewed my GeoPoint
  But nothing functions for me...

My libs are the next...

- android-support-v4.jar
- osmdroid-android-3.0.7.jar
- osmdroid-android-3.0.7-javadoc.jar
  -slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar

my sources are:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mapasasmdroid;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256); //constructor
       mapView.setClickable(true);
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       setContentView(mapView); //displaying the MapView
       mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
       mapView.getController().setZoom(15); //set initial zoom-level, depends on your need
       mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(-16,528484,-68.109397));
       //mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(,));
       mapView.setUseDataConnection(true); 
       mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
     }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapasasmdroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please Help Me!! I really need this...

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the map from your memory you are using this code:

```
 map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

Therefore images stored in your device must be in the correct format and hierarchy which should be like this :

sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/MAPQUESTOSM/X/Y.png.tiles

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Internet permissions to your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then, at the end of `onCreate`, you need to add:

```
setContentView(mapView);
```

in order to show the view.

Comment: @Vrian7 I added a chunk that should fix your problem.

Comment: Osmdroid works without `Internet` permission. Strange though!

Answer (score 0):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        map.setUseDataConnection(true);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM); // Gets a server "valid" response.
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        // map.setUseDataConnection(true);// 
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint( 27.72,  85.32);
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(8);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```

This is the activity_main page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is for manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

What basically is the problem is that:
from Mobile atlas creator, the tiles are saved in .jpg format, whereas the auto downloading(caching) with OSMDroid library is downloading .png.tile format. So, all you need is to create tiles of .png.tile format and the setusedataconnection(false) and off the internet permission and it will automatically load data.  Cheers